# SSIS expression to replace year and keep date and month

Tags: date, datetime, ssis, expression, type-conversion

I have a birthday field in the raw data file of the format dd.mm.yyyy.
I need to replace the year with 2015 and keep the month and date the same from the file while reading it in.
The destination column is of the datetime format.
I was able to formulate the following expression but it kept throwing up an error from which i was not able to comprehend much.

```
"2015 -" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("mm",birthdate),2) + "-" + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,2,1252)DATEPART("dd",birthdate),2))
```

Any insight into this would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using VS 2012, I ran a test using a string variable testdate with the value "27.08.2014" and then applied your expression in the Expression Task replacing birthdate with @[User::testdate].  This resulted in the following error

> "The Expression cannot be evaluated....  Attempt to parse the
>   expression... failed.  The expression might contain an invalid toke,
>   an incomplete toke, or an invalid element.  It might not be
>   well-formed, or might be missing part of a required element such as a
>   parenthesis."

If your raw data file is text, then it is probably coming in as string, not formatted in datetime, even though it retains the dd.mm.yyyy format.  Therefore, if you are receiving a similar error, you'll need to treat it as a string. Try the following expression.

> "2015-" +  SUBSTRING(birthdate , 4, 2 ) + "-" + SUBSTRING(birthdate ,
>   1, 2 )

In place of "birthdate", I applied my @[User::testdate] variable (with a value of "27.08.2014") in the above and it worked fine returning the following evaluated value.

> 2015-08-27

Afterward, you can then convert the value to datetime if using it to populate a database table.  Hope this helped.